# How build hadoop sources under windows?

Tags: java, apache, maven, hadoop

Trying to build hadoop from sources under windows 7 x64. According to instructions [Hadoop2OnWindows](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows) and [BUILDING](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/branches/branch-2/BUILDING.txt?view=markup)

I cloned hadoop sources from [git](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common), checkout to `origin/branch-2.5` (SHA-1: fa3bb675a728105d69614f53abe4339958550adf)
Then from windows console I run:

1. `set Platform=x64`
2. `clean install -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar`

And get error - `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 'protoc --version' did not return a version -> [Help 1]`

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

The first thing the protoc mojo of the hadoop-maven-plugins does is it uses Java's `java.lang.Process` class to attempt to execute the following command:

```
protoc --version
```

Basically it is doing this to check that the version of Protocol Buffer compiler (protoc) on your system matches the version of the `protobuf` JAR.

There are 4 outcomes for this:

- it couldn't find the `protoc` command to execute (it receives an exit value of 127)
- it does *not* receive the exit value of 127, but also doesn't get a version value returned
- a version is returned but doesn't match that of the protobuf jar
- a version is returned and it does match that of the protobuf jar

You are experiencing the 2nd issue.

If you try running `protoc --version` from the command line does it work?

As they state in their website, if you have multiple versions of `protoc` in your system, you can set in your build shell the `HADOOP_PROTOC_PATH` environment variable to point to the one you want to use for the Hadoop build. If you don't define this environment variable, `protoc` is looked up in the `PATH`. Is it available on your `PATH`?

If you haven't installed the  Protocol Buffer compiler you can downloaded it from the following location:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the `protoc` compiler.

You can download and install the `2.5.0` binary from [here](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/Download)

Then you can set `HADOOP_PROTOC_PATH` to point to the install directory.

Comment: To build protobuf on Mac/OsX
Download: https://protobuf.googlecode.com/files/protobuf-2.5.0.tar.bz2

compile protocol buffers with clang/libc++:

 tar xfvj protobuf-2.5.0.tar.bz2
 cd protobuf-2.5.0
 ./configure CC=clang CXX=clang++ CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O3 -g' LDFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++' LIBS="-lc++ -lc++abi"
 make -j 4 
 sudo make install

See https://wiki.ripple.com/OSX_Build_Instructions